# \medskip after every paragraph

Tags: spacing, line-breaking, line-spacing

After every paragraph I write, I use `\medskip` all the time e.g.

```
\begin{document}

test test test

\medskip

test test test

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to automate this so I don't need to type in `\medskip` all the time?

Also, out of interest, `medskip` is defined as `6pt plus 2pt minus 2pt` for `book` and `article` classes. But why not simply 6pt?

Comment: The `plus` and `minus` bit are not literally `6+2-2=6`, they allow for stretchable space (can stretch by 2pt) and shrinkable space (can shrink by 2pt), so that you get 6pt that may stretch or shrink a bit.

Comment: But to your real question: Something like `\setlength{\parskip}{\medskipamount}` should do it. (You may or may not want to set `\parindent` to zero: `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The space between paragraphs is controlled by `\parskip`, you can set that length to `\medskipamount` (the length of `\medskip`).

You may or may not want to additionally set `\parindent` to zero.

It is slightly more comfortable to let the package `parskip` do that for you. (It also patches a few commands to avoid additional excessive space, so it is usually preferred over simply changing `\parskip` for the whole document.) The code below assumes `parskip` v2 (2018-08-24) or above.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[skip=\medskipamount]{parskip}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

[image: Paragraphs separated with \medskip]

Some document classes may offer additional interfaces to change `\parskip` and friends that should be preferred over just setting `\parskip` directly. With KOMA-Script classes you would either be using the `parskip` option or `\setparsizes{<indent>}{<skip>}{<last line end-space>}`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\setparsizes{0pt}{\medskipamount}{0pt plus 1fil}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

[image: Paragraphs separated with \medskip]

---

The `plus` and `minus` bit are not literally `6+2-2=6`, they allow for stretchable space (can stretch by 2pt) and shrinkable space (can shrink by 2pt), so that you get 6pt that may stretch or shrink a bit.